# Como puedo usar java-stream para filtrar los objetos de una determinada clase de los elementos de una lista

Tags: java, lista, java-stream

Tengo una clase que contiene como propiedades varias clases

```
class Master {
private Clase1 clase1;
private Clase2 clase2;`introducir el código aquí`
LocalDateTime registeredDatTime;
...
}
```

Recibo un List listaMaster y quiero obtener partir de esta lista dos listas List y List
Ahora mismo estoy realizando el típico bucle.

```
List<Clase1> listaClase1 = new ArrayList<>();
for (Master master: listaMaster){
    listaClase1.add(master.getClase1);
}
```

Pero quería saber como puedo obtener el mismo resultado usando el chain Stream y aplicando un filtro por ejemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo podrías hacer de dos veces:

```
List<Clase1> listaClase1 = listaMaster.stream().map(t -> t.getClase1()).collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Clase2> listaClase2 = listaMaster.stream().map(t -> t.getClase2()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

En cada una de ellas, con "map" transformas cada elemento de la lista, y con "collect" lo conviertes a una lista.

Comment: También puedes utilizar una referencia al método y te queda incluso más fácil de leer al indicar que tipo de dato estás recibiendo en el `map`: `listaMaster.stream().map(Master::getClase1).collect(Collectors.toList());`